# CachingConnectionFactory confirm type simple vs correlated

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

What is difference between CachingConnectionFactory confirm type simple vs correlated.

Answer (score 1):

`correlated` means you pass in some correlation data with the send and you receive a callback when the confirm is received; the callback gets the correlation data - so you know which send the confirmation is for. You can wait on a `Future<?>` in the correlation data, which can also contain a returned message if it was returned.

With `simple`, it just means you can block waiting for the confirms for all the messages you sent have been received (`waitForConfirmsOrDie`). With simple confirms there is no correlation provided.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/2.2.6.RELEASE/reference/html/#template-confirms

and

https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/2.2.6.RELEASE/reference/html/#scoped-operations

Comment: Thanks a lot, I haven't seen someone this active. I tried both the approaches in first approach the response comes asynchronous, in second it is synchronous is it right assumption??

Comment: The acks come back asynchronously, but the `waitForConfirmsOrDie` blocks until they arrive (or times out).

Comment: Ok let me try it, the method waitForConfirmOrDie returns Boolean value does it mean if it true the message reached to the exchange and vice versa?

Comment: See the javadocs for `Channel` (amqp-client). It returns true if all acks are good and throws an exception if any of the acks was bad.

Comment: Thanks a ton Gary ❤